# Wordpress Header Not Showing on Sub Pages

Tags: multisite

My header image and top menu are not showing up on my event and category subpages. Is the correct path for the wp_head not being used? Help! http://northpalmbeach.localmusicfinders.com/category/jupiter/

This shows the correct purple header graphic and top menu: http://northpalmbeach.localmusicfinders.com/calendar/

Comment: We can't tell anything about the code that actually creates that header by looking at the website. Please post the code of the header.php and the taxonomy or custom post type templates.

Comment: I don't have a header.php file in my theme folder -- not sure where it is pulling the header image and menu from.  It works on all pages except those in the lmf.com/works/doesnotwork/

Answer (score -1):

My guess is your Head navigation is not called in `header.php`

check you file `page.php` and see the lines following `<?php get_header(); ?>`

if the lines below introduce header navigation either move them into header or copy them into same location in your `single.php` file

Comment: or check the template file you are using on calendar page

Comment: This is my code in my page.php file:   <?php wp_head(); ?>
    
</head>
<?php do_action('theme_after_head'); ?>
<?php ob_start(); // body start ?>

Comment: I don't have a header.php file in my theme folder

Comment: single.php has the same code above as in page.php file

Comment: @jmalone, search for 'theme_after_head' in your theme files, specifically something that looks like `add_action('theme_after_head', `. Once you've located it, you need to look for a function named whatever the second argument after 'theme_after_head' is. That will lead you to the theme header. You'll need to keep following the clues like that until you track down the logic that displays that header.

Comment: @guiniveretoo, in my functions.php file it has add_action('theme_after_head', 'theme_clear_cart_after_payment'); -- this seems to be a woocommerce command, I do not use shopping on my site

Comment: @guiniveretoo, could it be the wp-head file is not being seen because it is in the sub folder: lmf.com/works/doesnotwork -- appreciate your patience in helping me locate the issue

Comment: There can be multiple `add_action('theme_after_head')` function calls. Look specifically in your theme folder, it most likely won't be in a plugin.

Comment: Potentially we're barking up the wrong tree here. Look at the html output for the main header that disappears; find something that always appears in it, like a css class that's unlikely to appear elsewhere in the page. Search your theme folder for that css class.

Comment: the add_action('theme_after_head') only appears in the theme/master folder for all three sites -- I think you're right, good idea, but we are barking up the wrong tree on that.  I will search the html code for a css class and search my theme folder.  I know this will be a simple fix once we find it!  So aggravating now . . .